# Foursquare Merchant API call to retrieve limit of number of active Campaigns

Tags: foursquare

Is there a possibility to increase the number of campaigns running for a merchant (currently limited to 2)? If so, is there API call to retrieve actual limit? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're limited to two *active* campaigns per *venue*. You can create more, non-active campaigns if you'd like, but there can't be more than two active specials on a given venue.

Comment: With the new Foursquare changes, I can now run more than 2 active specials. I can also run an already active special multiple times.